# How do Synchronized Lists Work?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am not sure I understand Synchronized Lists in Java. Suppose I have the following:

```
 List<Integer> numbers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());

 // Assumption: This is running on a separate thread
 public void add() {
      numbers.add(new Random().nextInt(100));
 }

 // This is also running on a separate thread
 public void doSomething() {
      synchronized(numbers) {
           for (int i : numbers) {}
      }
 }
```

Basically, will the `add()` be able to add numbers to the list if `doSomething()` is invoked? What would happen if I instead used `public synchronized void add()` and `public synchronized void doSomething()`?

I am working on a UDP Socket Server, and I was going to store clients in an `ArrayList`. I would have multiple threads that can read, write, and modify this list. What should I be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the add() be able to add numbers to the list if doSomething() is invoked?

No, not until the thread invoking doSomething() leaves the synchronized block.

> What would happen if I instead used public synchronized void add() and public synchronized void doSomething()?

Assuming these are the only places where the list is used, the effect would be the same. But you would syncronize on the object containing the list rather than synchronizing on the list itself.

Basically, all the accesses to a shared state must be synchronized on the same lock. You choose the lock that you prefer. Instead of using a sychronized list, or synchronized methods, you could use a concurrent collection like a CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Comment: I'm confused; someone else said otherwise.

Comment: @BrandonSmith, this answer explains your code behavior clearly, since both operations are synchronized on the same object in either case.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. According to the docs for [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29), the list mutator methods (`add()`, etc.) synchronize on the list object itself. Since your iteration loop is also inside a `synchronized` block, all should be well.

Comment: @@BrandonSmith - Forget my earlier answer. Your code is fine.

Comment: I am not sure what "your code is fine" means. To state it explicitly, the add() will NOT be able to add numbers to the list if doSomething() is processing.

Comment: @Integrator - True, a call to `add()` will block until `doSomething()` exits the synchronized code. It is perfectly safe to call `add()` while `doSomething()` is executing. OP was wondering about making the methods `synchronized` as an alternative; that would behave exactly the same way as far as blocking goes and would provide no additional protection. Hence the current code is fine.