# Optimized solution to add elements in a list from two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads `T1` and `T2` and a List `AList` .I am trying to insert elements to `AList` from `T1` and `T2` .Inorder to make my list thread safe I have made it to synchronized List using `Collections.synchronizedList(observations);`

will the thread `T2` wait while `T1` is inserting to `AList` and vice versa?

Is there any optimized solution for adding elements from different threads to a single list?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780807/how-do-synchronized-lists-work